# Detecting Windows OSes on other partitions

Tags: windows, operating-system

What is the good way to check if the current computer is configured for dual/multi boot.

If my active Windows OS is on D drive, I would like to check if there is any other Windows installed on other drives C:, E:, F: etc

Basically I want paths to Program Files and Windows folders for each OS installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will find this information in a file called **boot.ini** which is located in the root of the active partition.

The file won't contain drive letters but partition numbers and disk numbers.

Windows Vista has the BCD which is a file in the same format as the windows registry.

The Program Files folder location can be found inside the windows registry.

Comment: But Vista doesn't use boot.ini anymore. It stores information internally that needs to be edited using BCDEDIT.exe

Answer (score 0):

Check these pages in Wikipedia:

- [Windows Vista startup process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_startup_process) (applies to Windows Server 2008 as well)
- [Windows NT startup process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_startup_process) (applies to Windows 2000, XP and Server 2003 as well)